# Run Button is grayed out in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm trying out the TeamTreehouse Android tutorial, and I am trying to run the CrystalBall project in Android Studio.  I'm running on Mac OS X 10.8

However, when I go to run it, the button is grayed out. I have already started the emulator. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: it seems like this problem has fixed itself. the run button is appearing again.